# can i get sim serial number from ios mobile for my ios app using ios programming?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, codenameone

I created my app on codename one and converted into ios app but i want to get sim serial number for user authentication. can i get sim serial number from my ios app ios native code in codename one and is it possible to get sim serial number from ios mobile using ios programming?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do on iOS which is why all 3rd party apps go through a process like this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-send-device-activation-sms-via-twilio.html